# How get result of last 2 hour from google using python?

Tags: python, urllib, google-search-api

I have a search topic "leo messi". I want to get all blog about "leo messi" posted in last 2 hours. Now i am stuck here.This code not filtering blog and time

```
import urllib
import json as m_json
query = "leo messi"
query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
json = m_json.loads ( response )
results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
for result in results:
    title = result['title']
    url = result['url']   # was URL in the original and that threw a name error exception
    print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

Comment: Have you tried using the resulting URL directly on a browser to see what it returns?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#st_params) google API provides only `dateRestrict` parameter which allows you to add those restrictions:

> Restricts results to URLs based on date. Supported values include:
>
> - d[number]: requests results from the specified number of past days.
> - w[number]: requests results from the specified number of past weeks.
> - m[number]: requests results from the specified number of past months.
> - y[number]: requests results from the specified number of past years.

Although after more detailed search I found [this](http://www.rankpanel.com/blog/google-search-parameters/) which shows `tbs=qdr` parameter which could be used as followed:

> You can specify different time periods
>
> - tbs=qdr:s – previous second
> - tbs=qdr:n – previous minute
> - tbs=qdr:h – previous hour
> - tbs=qdr:d – previous day
> - tbs=qdr:w – previous week
> - tbs=qdr:m – previous month
> - tbs=qdr:y – previous year

But I have no idea whether it'll work with websearch api.